# Figma Android Large Frame with Material 3 Design Kit

Tags: figma

Figma provides `Android Large` frame whose dimension is 360x800.
However, Material 3 Kit(https://www.figma.com/community/file/1035203688168086460) provides 412x892 and their aspect ratios are different.
How could I apply the Material 3 design to the frame properly?